# Async function unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, axios, electron

At the moment I am working on an Electron app that is supplied with data via an API. The renderer calls a "backend function", which first gets the API key via Keytar and then executes the API call via axios.

The problem here is that Keytar always returns null/undefined, even if a similar function with the same functionality works without any problems, also because this point can only be reached if a valid API key is stored at all and this will also be queried by Keytar.

I am new to async/await-functions, maybe I didn't get something.

btw: Maybe the title doesn't fit too well, but I was a bit at a loss about this one.

(keytarService, username, baseUrl are globals)

Here is my code:

// Api-calling function

```js
async function makeCall(method_type, url_path, data_array) {
    keytar.getPassword(keytarService, username).then((apiKey) => {
        if (apiKey == null || apiKey == undefined) {
            return false;
        }
        axios({
            method: method_type,
            url: baseUrl + url_path,
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'X-AUTH-TOKEN': apiKey,
            },
            data: data_array,
        }).then(
            (response) => {
                return response.data;
            },
            (error) => {
                return false;
            }
        );
    });
}
```

//index_renderer.js

```js
webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
    apiMain
        .makeCall('GET', 'user/self')
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById('username_text').innerText =
                data.firstName + '' + data.lastName;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

---

Similar function which is working:

```js
async function isAuthenticated() {
    apiKey = await keytar.getPassword(keytarService, username);

    if (apiKey == null || apiKey == undefined) {
        return false;
    }

    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: baseUrl + '/api/isAuthenticated',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'X-AUTH-TOKEN': apiKey,
        },
        data: {},
    }).then(
        (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            if (!response.data.authenticated) {
                logout();
            }
            return response;
        },
        (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            logout();
            return error;
        }
    );
}
```

// call of the working function in main.js

```js
if (authProcess.isAuthenticated()) {
        mainwin.loadFile('index.html');
    } else {
        mainwin.loadFile('login.html');
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing important `return`s in MakeCall().

Try:

```
function makeCall(method_type, url_path, data_array) {

    // return this promise to MakeCall
    return  keytar.getPassword(keytarService, username).then((apiKey) => {
        if (apiKey == null || apiKey == undefined) {
            return false;
        }
        
        // return this promise to keytar.getPassword then()     
       return  axios({
            method: method_type,
            url: baseUrl + url_path,
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'X-AUTH-TOKEN': apiKey,
            },
            data: data_array,
        }).then(
            (response) => {
                return response.data;
            },
            (error) => {
                return false;
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: This was the solution, wow. So damn easy. I think Javascript is not that easy for a die-hard PHP developer.

Thank you very much!